# Get Last XML Child from Tree of All Same Name Children

Tags: php, xml

I'm struggling to parse this XML structure:

```
<BrowseNodes>
    <BrowseNode>
        <BrowseNodeId>6388960011</BrowseNodeId>
        <Name>Road Bike Frames</Name>
        <Ancestors>
            <BrowseNode>
                <BrowseNodeId>1266090011</BrowseNodeId>
                <Name>Bike Frames</Name>
                <Ancestors>
                    <BrowseNode>
                        <BrowseNodeId>3403201</BrowseNodeId>
                        <Name>Cycling</Name>
                        <Ancestors>
                            <BrowseNode>
                                <BrowseNodeId>706814011</BrowseNodeId>
                                <Name>Outdoor Recreation</Name>
                                <Ancestors>
                                    <BrowseNode>
                                        <BrowseNodeId>3375301</BrowseNodeId>
                                        <Name>Categories</Name>
                                        <IsCategoryRoot>1</IsCategoryRoot>
                                        <Ancestors>
                                            <BrowseNode>
                                                <BrowseNodeId>3375251</BrowseNodeId>
                                                <Name>Sports & Outdoors</Name>
                                            </BrowseNode>
                                        </Ancestors>
                                    </BrowseNode>
                                </Ancestors>
                            </BrowseNode>
                        </Ancestors>
                    </BrowseNode>
                </Ancestors>
            </BrowseNode>
        </Ancestors>
    </BrowseNode>
    <BrowseNode>
        <BrowseNodeId>11130424011</BrowseNodeId>
        <Name>Outdoor Recreation Features</Name>
        <Ancestors>
            <BrowseNode>
                <BrowseNodeId>3375251</BrowseNodeId>
                <Name>Sports & Outdoors</Name>
            </BrowseNode>
        </Ancestors>
    </BrowseNode>
</BrowseNodes>
```

As you can see, each child element has the same name. I've seen some examples using Xpath, etc... but can't seem to wrap my head around it. Additionally, I've tried counting the children, but that obviously just counts the first  level... so no dice there. Same with just trying to see all of the children of each  (pretend $nodes is BrowseNodes based on the xml above).

Ideally I'd like to snag the BrowseNode directly under `<IsCategoryRoot>1</IsCategoryRoot>`. Again, my first thought was to count the children of , but it sticks at the first level.

```
foreach($nodes->BrowseNode->children() as $child) {
    echo $child->getName() . "<br>";
}
```

Any help is appreciated. I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

Here is what is returned when the item is in simplexml (keep in mind I'm already working with a SimpleXML Object at this point - for example I'm accessing this as $whateverItem->BrowseNodes:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (1) {
  ["BrowseNode"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (3) {
    ["BrowseNodeId"]=>
    string(7) "3403551"
    ["Name"]=>
    string(19) "Resistance Trainers"
    ["Ancestors"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#9 (1) {
      ["BrowseNode"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#10 (3) {
        ["BrowseNodeId"]=>
        string(10) "6389526011"
        ["Name"]=>
        string(27) "Bike Trainers & Accessories"
        ["Ancestors"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#11 (1) {
          ["BrowseNode"]=>
          object(SimpleXMLElement)#12 (3) {
            ["BrowseNodeId"]=>
            string(7) "3403201"
            ["Name"]=>
            string(7) "Cycling"
            ["Ancestors"]=>
            object(SimpleXMLElement)#13 (1) {
              ["BrowseNode"]=>
              object(SimpleXMLElement)#14 (3) {
                ["BrowseNodeId"]=>
                string(9) "706814011"
                ["Name"]=>
                string(18) "Outdoor Recreation"
                ["Ancestors"]=>
                object(SimpleXMLElement)#15 (1) {
                  ["BrowseNode"]=>
                  object(SimpleXMLElement)#16 (4) {
                    ["BrowseNodeId"]=>
                    string(7) "3375301"
                    ["Name"]=>
                    string(10) "Categories"
                    ["IsCategoryRoot"]=>
                    string(1) "1"
                    ["Ancestors"]=>
                    object(SimpleXMLElement)#17 (1) {
                      ["BrowseNode"]=>
                      object(SimpleXMLElement)#18 (2) {
                        ["BrowseNodeId"]=>
                        string(7) "3375251"
                        ["Name"]=>
                        string(17) "Sports & Outdoors"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (1) {
  ["BrowseNode"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (3) {
      ["BrowseNodeId"]=>
      string(7) "3403551"
      ["Name"]=>
      string(19) "Resistance Trainers"
      ["Ancestors"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#11 (1) {
        ["BrowseNode"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#12 (3) {
          ["BrowseNodeId"]=>
          string(10) "6389526011"
          ["Name"]=>
          string(27) "Bike Trainers & Accessories"
          ["Ancestors"]=>
          object(SimpleXMLElement)#13 (1) {
            ["BrowseNode"]=>
            object(SimpleXMLElement)#14 (3) {
              ["BrowseNodeId"]=>
              string(7) "3403201"
              ["Name"]=>
              string(7) "Cycling"
              ["Ancestors"]=>
              object(SimpleXMLElement)#15 (1) {
                ["BrowseNode"]=>
                object(SimpleXMLElement)#16 (3) {
                  ["BrowseNodeId"]=>
                  string(9) "706814011"
                  ["Name"]=>
                  string(18) "Outdoor Recreation"
                  ["Ancestors"]=>
                  object(SimpleXMLElement)#17 (1) {
                    ["BrowseNode"]=>
                    object(SimpleXMLElement)#18 (4) {
                      ["BrowseNodeId"]=>
                      string(7) "3375301"
                      ["Name"]=>
                      string(10) "Categories"
                      ["IsCategoryRoot"]=>
                      string(1) "1"
                      ["Ancestors"]=>
                      object(SimpleXMLElement)#19 (1) {
                        ["BrowseNode"]=>
                        object(SimpleXMLElement)#20 (2) {
                          ["BrowseNodeId"]=>
                          string(7) "3375251"
                          ["Name"]=>
                          string(17) "Sports & Outdoors"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#10 (3) {
      ["BrowseNodeId"]=>
      string(11) "11130424011"
      ["Name"]=>
      string(27) "Outdoor Recreation Features"
      ["Ancestors"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#11 (1) {
        ["BrowseNode"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#12 (2) {
          ["BrowseNodeId"]=>
          string(7) "3375251"
          ["Name"]=>
          string(17) "Sports & Outdoors"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: try a recursive function , test if have child recall function if not return results

Answer (score 2):

Xpath allows you to fetch specific nodes from a document. In SimpleXML`SimpleXMLElement::xpath()` allows you to use Xpath expressions. The result is always an array of SimpleXMLElement objects (for a valid expression).  The expression depends on how you define 'last'.

The last `BrowseNode` element in the document at any level:

```
$nodes = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
var_dump($nodes->xpath('(//BrowseNode)[last()]'));
```

The "BrowseNode" elements at the deepest levels (multiple possible). Basically the "BrowseNode" elements that have no descendant with that name:

```
$nodes = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
var_dump($nodes->xpath('//BrowseNode[not(.//BrowseNode)]'));
```

Of course you can get all nodes that have an child IsCategoryRoot with the value 1, too. From there you can fetch the BrowseNode inside it:

```
$nodes = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
var_dump($nodes->xpath('//BrowseNode[IsCategoryRoot=1]/Ancestors/BrowseNode'));
```

Comment: So, at this moment I'm already working with a SimpleXML object (lets call it $whatever). So, I'm accessing BrowseNodes already as $whatever->BrowseNodes, and then I run $whatever->BrowseNodes->xpath('//BrowseNodes') for example, I just get 2 empty arrays. It is pretty frustrating. I've updated my question above to show the full xml response, and the SimpleXML objects. I just don't know why I'm getting so many empty arrays when I try to use xpath()

Comment: `//` is any node in document, a slash at the start of the expression means that it in the context of the document. Two slashes after each other mean all descendants (not only children). A dot is the current node, so `.//` is any descendant of the current node. You would need to use that to take the element node your SimpleXMLElement references into account. But your current mistake might be that you access `BrowseNodes` not `BrowseNode`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make recursivity, I'm not sure about methods of object but maybe you can try something like this :

```
$childs = $nodes->BrowseNode;

function recursiveParse($node){
   foreach($node->children() as $child) {
    echo $child->getName() . "<br>";
    $ances = $child->getAncestors();
    if($ances !== NULL)  recursiveParse($ances->BrowseNode);
  }
}

recursiveParse($childs);
```